# How can I use LEFT & RIGHT Functions in SQL to get last 3 characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `Char(15)` field, in this field I have the data below:

```
94342KMR
947JCP
7048MYC
```

I need to break down this, I need to get the last RIGHT 3 characters and I need to get whatever is to the LEFT. My issue is that the code on the LEFT is not always the same length as you can see.

How can I accomplish this in SQL?

Thank you

Comment: So, since this is a `char(15)` what are you expected results? All blanks or the last 3 non blank chars?

Comment: @KenWhite: OP uses [`sql-server`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) not [`mysql`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql).

Comment: You're right. I misread the tag. My fault. :-( Must be Monday here.

Comment: What you really want here is two columns, at least one of them should be varchar or nvarchar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT  RIGHT(RTRIM(column), 3),
        LEFT(column, LEN(column) - 3)
FROM    table
```

Use `RIGHT` w/ `RTRIM` (to avoid complications with a fixed-length column), and `LEFT` coupled with `LEN` (to only grab what you need, exempt of the last 3 characters).

if there's ever a situation where the length is <= 3, then you're probably going to have to use a `CASE` statement so the `LEFT` call doesn't get greedy.

Comment: its `char(15)` so probably not desired behaviour http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8e926/2

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RTRIM` or cast your value to `VARCHAR`:

```
SELECT RIGHT(RTRIM(Field),3), LEFT(Field,LEN(Field)-3)
```

Or

```
SELECT RIGHT(CAST(Field AS VARCHAR(15)),3), LEFT(Field,LEN(Field)-3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here an alternative using [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

```
SELECT
            SUBSTRING([Field], LEN([Field]) - 2, 3) [Right3],
            SUBSTRING([Field], 0, LEN([Field]) - 2) [TheRest]
    FROM 
            [Fields]
```

[**with fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8e926/20)

Answer (score 1):

```
select right(rtrim('94342KMR'),3)
```

This will fetch the last 3 right string.

```
select substring(rtrim('94342KMR'),1,len('94342KMR')-3)
```

This will fetch the remaining Characters.