# SQL Server message 547

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraints

I want to make `Kode_Barang` 7 character with first character Must 'B' and the the remaining character must be a number [1-9]

I have create query for Kode_Barang just like this :

```
Kode_Barang CHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY CHECK(LEN(Kode_Barang)=7 AND LEFT(Kode_Barang,1)='B' AND SUBSTRING(Kode_Barang,2,6)LIKE '[0-9]' )
```

But after I insert some values like this :

```
INSERT INTO Barang (Kode_Barang, Nama_Barang, Satuan, Harga, Stock) 
VALUES('B000001', 'Mie Goreng', 'Biji', 2500, 56)
```

There are an error occurred on `Kode_Barang`.

Is there anything wrong? Please I'm new to SQL query with check constraint.

NOTE for another reference :

```
Nama_Barang VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
Satuan VARCHAR (10) CHECK(Satuan = 'Buah' OR Satuan = 'Biji' OR Satuan  = 'CM' OR Satuan = 'KG' OR Satuan = 'DUS' OR Satuan = 'Lusin'),
Harga MONEY NOT NULL CHECK(Harga != 0)
Stock INT NOT NULL CHECK(Stock > -1)
```

Thanks

I have tried it with '%[^0-9]%' but the result still  the same

I get reference like this one
[How can I use LEFT & RIGHT Functions in SQL to get last 3 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409605/how-can-i-use-left-right-functions-in-sql-to-get-last-3-characters)

That my datatype is `CHAR` not `VARCHAR`.

And I change the code like this :

```
Kode_Barang CHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY 
     CHECK(LEN(Kode_Barang) = 7 
           AND SUBSTRING(CAST(Kode_Barang AS VARCHAR(7)), 1, 1) = 'B' 
           AND SUBSTRING(CAST(Kode_Barang AS VARCHAR(7)), 2, 6) LIKE '%[^0-9]%' ),
```

but still the same

Error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 44
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__Barang__Kode_Bar__5441852A". The conflict occurred in database "Studi_Kasus_Kelompok", table "dbo.Barang", column 'Kode_Barang'.

Thanks

Comment: Note that it's helpful to include the full text of any errors you receive in a question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your `SUBSTRING(Kode_Barang, 2, 6) LIKE '[0-9]'` is wrong. `LIKE '[0-9]'` will compare with a *single* digit. Perhaps try something like:

```
... SUBSTRING(Kode_Barang, 2, 6) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' ...
```

...which checks to see if *any* character in the resulting string is *not* numeric.

Comment: I have tried i, the result still the same, I have add some reference in the above.
thanks Matt Gibson

Comment: Note that in my version, I'm using `*NOT* LIKE`. You've edited my pattern into your question, but not the NOT.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CHECK` constraint should be:

```
CHECK(Kode_Barang LIKE 'B[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

This means that `Kode_Barang` should exactly be 7 characters that starts with a `B` and the remaining characters are numbers.