# Filtering records based on last 4/5 characters of VARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a VARCHAR column that contains an integer followed by a forward slash and a four digit integer.

**Example Data:**

```
82/2015
126/2017
5763/2017
```

I'm trying to retrieve only the records that end in 2017.

```
126/2017
5763/2017
```

I'm assuming I need to use the forward slash to split the string and then perform a comparison? Or maybe I could simply perform a comparison against the last 4/5 characters? Does SQL contain a function that can do either of these for me?

Comment: Hint: `RIGHT` function.

Comment: If you wanted to search that data, it should be in a separate field. This breaks the 1st NF. It also means that you can't use any index to speed up the query forcing a full table scan each time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use LEFT & RIGHT Functions in SQL to get last 3 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409605/how-can-i-use-left-right-functions-in-sql-to-get-last-3-characters)

Comment: You can create a *new* persisted computed column with `RIGHT(Thatfield,4)` and apply an index to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`RIGHT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql) to do this.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE RIGHT(SomeDate, 4) = '2017'
```

Comment: You might want to use string representation of 2017 like “2017”

Comment: @SurjitSD SQL will do a conversion from VARCHAR to INT, and his sample data doesn't contain any special characters. It would have worked as-is but your suggestion does make it more robust.

Answer (score 2):

Use `like`:

```
where col like '%/2017'
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution to the OP's problem.